# ASP.net MVC 3.0 page flow

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have previously used Spring MVC webflows in JAVA, wondering what is the equivalent in .net MVC for that? WorkFlow which is surely not what i need to page flows (eg: Registration using previous next  buttons). I am aware of Spring.Net as plugin but wondering if i am missing anything in .net or i have no option but to use Spring??

Many Thanks,

Comment: Check this out http://wfmvc.codeplex.com/ Also take a look at that examples they might be relevant to ASP.NET MVC 3 as well
[Using Workflow with ASP.NET MVC 4](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows-Workflow-dd54089e) and [ASP.NET MVC4 Workflow Enabled User Registration](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-MVC4-Workflow-c5daa4ab)